# Train LSTM models with particle swarm optimization in parallel on Google Colab

Tags: keras, parallel-processing, google-colaboratory, lstm

I construct an LSTM model and want to optimize the hyperparameters using particle swarm optimization. Since I am not familiar with parallel computation, I hope the computation could be economical in time and money. Refer to [text](https://saturncloud.io/blog/train-multiple-neural-networks-in-parallel-on-cpu-in-keras/), I construct the following code.

Creating a model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras import optimizers

def create_lstm(layn, uni, drp, lnr, clpn):
  regressor = Sequential()
  for k in range(layn):
    if k == 0:
      regressor.add(LSTM(units = uni, return_sequences = True,
                input_shape = (None, 1)))
    else:
      regressor.add(LSTM(units = uni, return_sequences = True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(drp))

  # Adding the output layer
  regressor.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units = 1)))

  # Compiling
  opt1 = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lnr,global_clipnorm=clpn)
  regressor.compile(optimizer = opt1, loss = 'mean_squared_error')
  return regressor
```

Training and computing the fitness:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import tensorflow as tf

def train_model(params):
  strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

  with strategy.scope():
    model = create_lstm(params['layn'],params['uni'],params['drp'],
         params['lnr'], params['clpn'])
  
  callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=params['pat'], restore_best_weights=True)
  history = model.fit(params['x'], params['y'], epochs = 10000, batch_size = params['bs'],
          sample_weight=params['sw'],
          validation_data=(params['x_val'], params['y_val'], params['vsw']), callbacks=[callback])

  # computing fitness
  fitness = ...

  return model_and_fitness
```

Part of my particle swarm optimization algorithm:

```
import random
import math
import multiprocessing as mp

def pso_lstm(x, y, x_val, y_val, x_test, y_test, sw, vsw):
  nop = 30 # number of particles
  maxit = 100 # maximum iteration number
  nod = 6 # number of dimensions
  c1, c2 = 2.0, 2.0

  # boundary of hyperparameter
  bon = np.array([[200, 1200], # unit number
          [0.0, 1.0], # dropout rate
          [-7.0, math.log10(0.5)], # log10(learning rate)
          [-7.0, math.log10(0.5)], # log10(global clipnorm)
          [50, 1000], # patience
          [3, 10]]) # log2(batch size)
  pos = np.zeros((nod, nop))
  vel = np.zeros((nod, nop))
  pbest = np.zeros((nod, nop))
  gbest = np.zeros((nod, nop))
  pbest_fit = 1E20 * np.ones(nop)
  gbest_fit = 1E20
  params_list = []
  # 起始化粒子位置與速度
  for i in range(nop): #粒子數
    pos[0, i] = random.randrange(200, 1201) # unit number
    pos[1, i] = random.uniform(0.2, 0.5) # dropout rate
    pos[2, i] = random.uniform(-7.0, math.log10(0.5)) # log10(learning rate)
    pos[3, i] = random.uniform(-7.0, math.log10(0.5)) # log10(global clipnorm)
    pos[4, i] = random.randrange(50, 1001) # patience
    pos[5, i] = random.randrange(3, 11) # log2(batch size)
    d1 = {'x': x, 'y': y, 'x_val': x_val, 'y_val': y_val,
        'x_test': x_test, 'y_test': y_test, 'sw': sw, 'vsw': vsw,
        'layn': 3,
        'uni': round(pos[0, i]),
        'drp': pos[1, i],
        'lnr': 10 ** pos[2, i],
        'clpn': 10 ** pos[3, i],
        'pat': round(pos[4, i]),
        'bs': 2 ** round(pos[5, i])}
    params_list.append(d1)

  gbest_fit2 = np.zeros(maxit)
  for j in range(maxit):
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())
    results = pool.map(train_model, params_list)
    # update the optimal personal fitness and position
    ...
    # update the optimal group fitness and position
    ...
    # update particle velocities and positions
    ...
    # modify params_list
    ...
  return optimal_model
```

The code related to parallel computation is

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

  with strategy.scope():
```

in train_model and

```
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())
    results = pool.map(train_model, params_list)
```

in pso_lstm.

Initially, I hope to train each model faster, and train models in parallel. However, I'm not clear about these two pieces of code, as well as the terminology, so I'm not clear how Google Colab allocates the GPU. When I executed `mp.cpu_count()`, I get 12. I also tried setting `nop = 1` and `maxit = 1` (train a model), and set unit=1200, patience=500, batch_size=1024 (with x.shape=(1763, 167, 1)), the computation takes more than 3 hours, and when echo=6000, the validation loss is reduced compared to when the echo is hundreds, but the available GPUs went from ~50 to 0. Because I am not familiar with Colab, is there a more cautious and efficient way to execute it? I think I can reduce and separate the patience and find the more efficient hyperparameters. Could you please give more suggestions to modify the code?

In addition, does the application of tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy() perform parallel computations on sub-batches? If it is possible to perform parallel computations on the gradient of the loss for each timestep?

Thank you very much!